# How to get the screen awake time of a device in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, usage-statistics

I am aware of UsageStats but it only has statistics for apps. How to get the total time spent on the device in intervals daily, weekly, monthly, yearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't find the screen awake time, but we can run a foreground service with an infinite loop that increments the value of counter every second when the screen is on.

Put the below code in the service.

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);

Handler handler= new Handler(); 
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() { 
if( powerManager.isScreenOn()){
counter++;
 }
 } 
}; 
handler.postDelayed(myRunnable,1000);
```

counter shows the time in seconds.